# Is there a way to mark questions as read?

Tags: support

I would be happy to dig into answered and unanswered questions, new or old (as far as I know about the subject), but I saw that many "unanswered" questions are actually answered either directly (and not marked as such by the user posting it) or only in the comment section. Those questions of course appear as unanswered while I consider they are done.

I am not asking about flagging those questions as answered for the whole community but I have the tendency to forget which questions I already looked at and was wondering if there is a way to mark them as read (only for me of course) or something similar so that I know I shouldn't open them anymore. Is this possible? I know I could use the "favorite" flag but I don't want to use it as a "read" or "unread" flag.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I don't think there is such a feature. You could use webbrowser bookmarks to highlight stuff to read later though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run across questions that are answered in the comments, you can

1. Ping the commenter who answered it in the comments requesting they convert their comments to an answer. When this is done, a simple upvote will remove the post from the unanswered queue.
2. If the user refuses or is no longer active, you can turn their comments into a community wiki answer and again an upvote will remove the post from the unanswered queue.
3. If you don't think the comments or current answer suffice, you can write your own answer.

I mentioned [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2900/12909) about a chat room we dedicate in math to unanswered questions. When we do 1, 2, or 3 listed above, we post a link in the chat room so users can read the answer and vote appropriately if warranted to clear the queue. Of course, bio would need their own dedicated chat room since posting in math may raise eyebrows if it is bio.